# Installing Google V8 in CentOS 7, missing a few files

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, centos7

I'm following [these steps](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/forge/installed-v8js/replies/58405) to compile Google V8 for v8js extension in CentOS 7:

```
cd /tmp

git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git
export PATH=`pwd`/depot_tools:"$PATH"

fetch v8
cd v8

make native library=shared -j2

chrpath -r '$ORIGIN' out/native/lib.target/libv8.so

sudo mkdir -p /tmp/v8-install/lib /tmp/v8-install/include
sudo cp out/native/lib.target/lib*.so /tmp/v8-install/lib/
sudo cp -R include/* /tmp/v8-install/include
echo -e "create /tmp/v8-install/lib/libv8_libplatform.a\naddlib out/native/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_libplatform.a\nsave\nend" | sudo ar -M
```

The problem is that `make native library=shared` is missing the entire folder  `/tools/gyp/` where `libv8_libplatform.a`,so I'm stuck at this step

```
echo -e "create /tmp/v8-install/lib/libv8_libplatform.a\naddlib out/native/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_libplatform.a\nsave\nend" | sudo ar -M  <== no file found!
```

I have tried `make release library=shared -j2` but it comes up a new problem. There is no `lib.target/libv8.so` in `out/Release/` directory.
Has anyone had experience installing Google V8 in CentOs 7? Could you figure out the problem?

Comment: Can't you use `v8` from EPEL?

Comment: @Sven, the repository that i have found so far are 3.14, which isn't compatible with v8js extendsion. Do you know of any higher versions of `v8` in the yum repositories?